# Past perfect and use of "and"

Tags: grammar

1 - When she had entered the room, she found  him laid on the floor with the box in his right hand.

2-she had entered the room and found him laid on the floor with the box in his right hand.

3-she entered the room and found him laid on the floor with the box in his right hand.

My question - in 1st sentence - past perfect + simple past.

In 3rd sentence I used  both sentences in simple past with help of "and".

Is it possible - present perfect +simple past or we have to make sure simple past +simple past While using "and"
In short my second sentence is right or wrong?

Comment: First you're going to have to get your verb right.  "To lie" (stretch out) is *lie*, *lay*, *lain*, *lying*.  "To lay" (put down) is *lay*, *laid*, *laid*, *laying*.  "To lie" (tell an untruth) is *lie*, *lied*, *lied*, *lying*.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is grammatically fine. In this case, there is an implied hidden 'had' after the 'and': She had entered the room and [she had] found him...

However, you probably didn't mean to say 'found him laid on the floor'. 'Laid' means that someone had been carrying him and that they put him down carefully on the floor. Unless that's your intention, you should say 'found him lying on the floor'.